# node_http_parser parser error at line 1096 with NodeJS 18.17.0 upgrade

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Planning for NodeJS 18.17.0 upgrade, it is working in my local setup but same is not working Kubernetes environment. Getting below error after starting my node application. have verified all the node modules from my local setup with the K8 pod, it seems fine. Any inputs on this or how to debug this further will be more helpful...

```
    node[1]: ../src/node_http_parser.cc:1096:static void node::{anonymous}::ConnectionsList::Expired(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[0]->IsNumber()' failed.
    1: 0xb83f50 node::Abort() [node]
    2: 0xb83fce  [node]
    3: 0xba415a  [node]
    4: 0xdc28b0  [node]
    5: 0xdc3def v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
    6: 0x17036b9  [node]

    Planning for NodeJS 18.17.0 upgrade. 
    node[1]: ../src/node_http_parser.cc:1096:static void node::                      {anonymous}::ConnectionsList::Expired(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion     `args[0]->IsNumber()' failed.
    1: 0xb83f50 node::Abort() [node]
    2: 0xb83fce  [node]
    3: 0xba415a  [node]
    4: 0xdc28b0  [node]
    5: 0xdc3def v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*)         [node]
    6: 0x17036b9  [node]
```